# Возвращение значения из асинхронного запроса

Tags: java, android-asynctask, callback

Доброго времени суток!
Имеется работа с REST api при помощи retrofit2.
Запросы осуществляются асинхронно, пример приведен ниже.

```
    public String identifyLanguage(String text) {
    String result = "";

    translatorApi.getIdentifyLanguage(ConstantManager.TRANSLATE_API_KEY, text).enqueue(new Callback<LanguageIdentifyModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LanguageIdentifyModel> call, Response<LanguageIdentifyModel> response) {
            //Возвращаем результат
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LanguageIdentifyModel> call, Throwable t) {
            //Поражение
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Нет никакой проблемы вставлять тело данного метода везде, где необходимо получить результат, но хочется вместо этого производить простой вызов функции по типу

```
identifyLanguage("Some text");
```

Но если оставить метод в приведенном выше виде, выход из функции будет произведен до того, как асинхронный запрос получит результат.
Соответственно возник вопрос: есть ли какие-либо легальные способы реализовать метод, который возвращает результат выполнения асинхронного запроса?

Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Меня тут из астрала спрашивают: надо дернуть просто identifyLanguage("Some text"), или синхронно получить еще и какой-то ответ, а дожидаясь результата, поспать?

Comment: Прошу прощения, да. Второе. Есть асинхронный запрос. Из него хочется синхронно получить результат.

Comment: Из асинхронного метода получить результат синхронно не получится. Можно передавать коллбэк, ну или использовать Rx.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так и сделайте оберточку, в которую выведите только то, что у вас меняется, а на выходе удобные аргументы

Для классов на основе AsyncTask есть метод get(), для тредов можно сделать Thread.join(), для чего-то более крутого есть мутексы, на которых можно спать до тех пор, пока из отдельного треда не разбудят. А как мы проснулись, то получаем результат и отдаем его дальше.

Правда тут есть пара нюансов:

1. Так как запросы асинхронные, то будут порождаться новые треды или какие-то задачи, что в общем-то нам не надо. Это потребление лишних ресурсов. Но с современным отношением к программированию на это всем наплевать.
2. Так как был упомянут АсинкТаск, то могу предположить, что работа должна быть в Андроиде. Работать с сетью можно только не из основного юи-треда, т.е. все вот это выше описанное, делаем или из своего треда, или из АсинкТаска. От чего получается, что мы запускаем тред из треда, таск из таска, что явный оверхед, как описано в пункте 1.